# How to find the previous quarter value based on current quarter in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I need to find the value of the previous quarter for a particular given date. Like for example, I passed a date as on 12th January, 2015, I need the result to be as 4th quarter of 2014.

If I use the below query, I get the result as 0

```
SELECT EXTRACT(quarter FROM '2015-01-01'::timestamp) - 1;

Result : 0
```

Can someone let me know how do I get me desired result as mentioned above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to "trunc" the date to the beginning of its quarter, the subtract a day, and then get the quarter for that date:

```
extract(quarter from date_trunc('quarter', date '2015-01-01')::date - 1)
```

If you want to get the year *and* the quarter you need to use `to_char()` instead:

```
to_char(date_trunc('quarter', date '2015-01-01')::date - 1, 'yyyy-q');
```

Comment: What if I want to get the previous 3 quarters?? For January 2015, I need the last three quarters of 2014...

Comment: @YousufSultan: then you repeat the above code in a loop applying the same principle. Btw: it's not very nice to change the scope of your question later on after you receive an answer. You should always state your _complete_ problem right from the beginning.

Comment: Apologies for my miscommunication.... will make sure I put forward my exact requirement from next time onwards...